# Placing a button relatively to an irregular imageview shape

Tags: android, android-launcher

I need to place the button(green) at the place shown on the image(red).
It should be the same for all kind of phone screens in portrait mode.

This is the middle of the screen but the height is changing according to the screen size. These are the properties of the button. `android:layout_marginBottom` is not true for all screens sizes.

**Button**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />
```

**Irregular shape**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/irregular_shape" />
```

**Wanted result**

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything? how does your code look?

Comment: @DroiDev, edited the post

Comment: ummmm... can you show more than that? what is the red made from? ImageView? the 'button' i am assuming is a Button

Comment: if the red part wont contain anything else, just make that a clickable field...

Comment: @DroiDev I am aware of the hack, but I have button state and the design will be for many screens. Don't want to increase the size of the apk with many images.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to solve this is to separate your irregular shape into two shapes, and than place the button between the shapes with ConstraintLayout, something like this:

[shapes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x9Hy.png)

And the code would be something like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shape2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/shape_bank_bill_dotted_transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/shape1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/shape1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shape1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/shape_bank_bill_dotted_transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```